# How many subsets of an $n$-element set contain $k$ or more elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So I know you could do this the tedious way of:

$(nCk) + (nCk_{+1}) + ... + (nCk_{=n})$

or the somewhat less tedious, but still not ideal:

$2^n - [(nC0) + (nC1) + ... + (nCk_{-1})]$

However, this problem to me is just screaming to think of it in terms of an $n$-bit integer, where a $1$ represents an element being present, a $0$ not present. so I guess what im asking is:

**How would you determine the number of $n$-bit integers that contain at least $k$ $1$s?**

Forgive me if my formatting is off, this is my first post. Tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is actually notoriously tough, and I do not believe it has a closed form solution. Note that, by symmetry, this is equivalent to summing over the first $k$ binomial coefficients, and then see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

Comment: Haha. Well now I feel silly. New to discrete maths, but have found even these elementary counting techniques quite interesting. Thanks for the response!